Deriving the relationship of Cp - Cv in terms of P, T, V, and H
We're learning the relationship between Cp and Cv. We seem to be doing it a little uniquely because we're looking for equations of Cp - Cv in terms of P, T, V, and U, and in terms of P, T, V, and H
For the first one, which was also isobaric, this was the process:
H = U + PV 
dH = dU + d(PV)
dH = dU + PdV + VdP 0
dH = dU + PdV
(∂H/∂T)P = (∂U/∂T)P + P(∂V/∂T)P
Cp = (∂U/∂T)P + P(∂V/∂T)P [ EQN 1 ]
dU = CvdT + (∂U/∂V)TdV
(∂U/∂T)P = Cv (∂T/∂T)P 1 + (∂U/∂V)T(∂V/∂T)P
(∂U/∂T)P = Cv + (∂U/∂V)T(∂V/∂T)P [ EQN 2 ]
Plug EQN 2 into EQN 1 to get:
Cp = Cv + (∂U/∂V)T(∂V/∂T)P + P(∂V/∂T)P
Cp - Cv = (∂U/∂V)T(∂V/∂T)P + P(∂V/∂T)P
Cp - Cv = (∂V/∂T)P[ (∂U/∂V)T + P]
Now I'm supposed to derive an equation of Cp - Cv at isochoric conditions in terms of P, T, V, and H but I'm just completely lost in a lot of parts.
Supposedly the end equation is as follows:
Cp - Cv = (∂P/∂T)v [V-(∂H/∂P)T]
I tried starting from H = U + PV and got Cv = (∂H/∂T)V - V(∂P/∂T)V before realizing that's a dead-end.
I'm sure I'll need to start off from H = U + PV but that's as far as I can imagine. Even just where to start off in will be helpful to me. I'm just super stuck.

Are you sure that is the equation you are supposed to end up with?

Yes. That was what our professor gave us to derive on our own.

Ah actually @ChetMiller I made a mistake on the terms. It's supposed to be in terms of P,T, V, and H in Isochoric conditions. Sorry for that.

I don't know about the isochoric constraint, but in general,  $$dH=C_pdT+\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right)_TdP$$so,$$dU=dH-VdP-PdV$$$$dU=C_pdT+\left[\left(\frac{\partial  H}{\partial P}\right)_T-V\right]dP-PdV$$
So, $$C_v=C_p+\left[\left(\frac{\partial  H}{\partial P}\right)_T-V\right]\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V$$
